# How to get dynamically generated image name in android

Tags: android

i want to get image name on click of image which is created dynamically......

```
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        final ImageButton b=new ImageButton(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
        layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
        b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Resources res = getResources();
        int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("_"+list.get(i).toString(), "drawable", getPackageName() );
        b.setImageResource( resourceId );
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //at here i want to get the selected image name


            }
        });
        rowoptions.addView(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the image's name as the `ImageButton` tag. You can then retrieve it in `onClick()`. Use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for this:

```
    String imageName = "_" + list.get(i).toString();
    int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName() );
    b.setTag(imageName);
    b.setImageResource(resourceId);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //at here i want to get the selected image name
          String clickedImageName = (String)v.getTag();

        }
    });
```